# Elasticsearch 5 search_before

Tags: elasticsearch

Is their any `search_before` doing the same, but reversed, as `search_after` in Elasticsearch 5?

If you wonder why would I need such a feature:
I'm trying to do the same as Facebook comments, when you click on a comment notification on a post you are watching, you jump directly to the comment and you have a button to load the following comments (next page with `search_after`) or previous comments (previous page, `search_before`).

Cheers

Comment: No there isn't. I'm curious to know why you'd need to paginate like that.

Comment: I was thinking maybe reverse the sorting and using `search_after`? But this means it needs to be sorted already.

Comment: @Val I edited the question to answer why I'd need to paginate like that